# Form doesn't submit on Firefox

Tags: forms, firefox, submit, form-submit, submit-button

```
<table width=100% cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 class="form_table">

<form name="suggestion_box" action="suggestion_box.php" method=post>
<input type="hidden" name="form_submit" value="1">
<tr>
<td width=40% align=right valign=top class="form_label_cell">
<b class="form_label">
First Name<br>
</b>
</td>
</table>
<br>
<input type="image" src="button_submit.gif" alt="Submit" class="input_gfx">
<input type="hidden" name="form_submit" value="1">
<br>
</form>
</table>
```

This is my form, I don't know why that doesn't work with Firefox, can you help me?
I've been reading hundreds of answers since weeks ago, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: How are you submitting the form. It only works when you have 

<input type='submit' /> as submit button.

Comment: you can't put `<form>` element inside `<table>` element.

Comment: try validating your code as a valid html then edit your question with new code if you have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

1) You can't place your form within the table like that.

2) You are closing your table (`</table>`) twice.

3) You never closed your row (`</tr>`).

Try this simplified code instead:

```
<form name="suggestion_box" action="suggestion_box.php" method=post>

   <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="form_table">

      <tr>
         <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="form_submit" value="1">
         </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td>
            <b class="form_label">
               First Name
            </b>
         </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
         <td>
            <input type="submit" src="button_submit.gif" alt="Submit" class="input_gfx">
         </td>
      </tr>

   </table>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify a name for your image input field.

```
<input type="image" name="yourimage" src="button_submit.gif" alt="Submit" class="input_gfx">
```

You can access the x/y values using the POST variables yourimage.x / yourimage.y (or in PHP yourimage_x, yourimage_y).

Comment: thanks, I gave a name to the image but it still doesn't work.

<input type="image" name="button_submit" src="button_submit.gif" alt="Submit" class="input_gfx">

Comment: if I use <input type="submit" /> I will get that dummy submit button and I don't want that.

Answer (score -1):

I have had problem with forms and inputs which don't have id's, Try giving id's to the form and form elements and add type="submit" to your submit button.

Comment: it has nothing to do with `id`